# How can we duplicate basic Azure cli commands inside Docker cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, docker, powershell

Is there a way to use Docker cli commands to run some basic commands across cloud platforms without using their proprietary cli interfaces ?

For instance, these commands in AZ:

```
az login --allow-no-subscriptions -o table
az account list -o table
az account set --subscription $subscriptionName
az account list-locations -o table
az group create  --name $resourceGroupName --location $location
az group list -o table
az acr create --name $containerRegistryName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --sku standard --admin-enabled true
az acr list -o table
```

Are there any Docker generics that will allow me to do the same for Azure and say .. AWS ?

-thanks,

Comment: What did you search for? What did you try? What happened? What do you mean by this ***commands across cloud platforms***? Are you aksing to say just use powershel.exe to  talk to Azure, AWS etc., in docker? Azure and AWS have there own modules for PowerShell to interop wiht their offereings.

Comment: I am confused to what Docker CLI commands you expect would be similiar to CLI commands for Azure. Docker is not a cloud platform. The docker CLI is well documented online.

Comment: Correct, just using PowerShell to talk to all those platforms thru Docker. I've been searching the web for some kind of plug in or extensions that we can add to Docker to avoid directly calling native Azure or AWS commands and do it directly thru Docker. I'm new to the whole DevOps scene ... pls forgive my myopic approach, if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think figured a way around. Since there's doesnt seem to be any plug in or extension around to do this, I decided to create my own wrapper. This will somewhat encapsulate the cloud provider's inner commands from the rest of my code. Basically, I'm pre-loading all of the relevant command lines I will be using in my code, and load it into a hashtable object. I proceed to prompt the user for cloud service they use and then map their selection to my pre-defined corresponding cloud object.

```
                # Remove choco

            Write-Host "Uinstalling choco, if exists ...."

            if (Test-Path "$env:ChocolateyInstall") {
               Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "$env:ChocolateyInstall" | Wait-Process
               [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace([Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::CurrentUser.OpenSubKey('Environment').GetValue('PATH', '', [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueOptions]::DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames).ToString(), [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Escape("$env:ChocolateyInstall\bin") + '(?>;)?', '', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase) | %{[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $_, 'User')}
               [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace([Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine.OpenSubKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\').GetValue('PATH', '', [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueOptions]::DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames).ToString(),  [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Escape("$env:ChocolateyInstall\bin") + '(?>;)?', '', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase) | %{[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $_, 'Machine')}
            }



            Write-Host "Installing choco"
            $env:ChocolateyInstall='C:\ProgramData\chocoportable'

            Invoke-WebRequest https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | Invoke-Expression 

            Write-Host "Installing Azure-CLI"
            choco install -y azure-cli

            Write-Host "---------------------------------------------------"

            Write-Host "Installing AWS"
            choco install -y awscli --version=1.16.238



            # ============ MAIN PIECE: WRAPPERS AROUND CLOUD-CLI NATIVE COMMANDS ==============

             $Azure = [PSCustomObject]@{name = 'Azure'; version = az --version;}
             $AWS = [PSCustomObject]@{name = 'AWS'; version = aws --version;}
             $cloudServices = @{}
             $cloudServices.Add('Azure',$Azure)
             $cloudServices.Add('AWS',$AWS)
             # =================================================================================



            # prompt providers choices
            [string[]]$choices = 'Azure', 'AWS', 'EXIT'


            $result = 0

            do {

                    $result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice("Select Current Cloud Service Provider", "Select from the following:", $choices, 0)

                    $cloudProvider =  $cloudServices[$choices[$result]]


                    Write-Host "Selection:" $choices[$result] 

                    Write-Host "Executing CLI command for: " $cloudProvider.name
                    $cloudProvider.version

            } while ($result -ne 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

NO. I am not sure why you need to do this.

CLI (command line interface) for a particular platform is meant for talking to that specific platform. Docker CLI can (and meant to be) talk to docker, Azure CLI to Azure, AWS CLI to AWS and so on.

One more thing. You mentioned

> just using PowerShell to talk to all those platforms thru Docker

You don't need to specifically use Powershell though. All these CLIs work in the command shell of your platform (e.g. Bash, CMD etc.)

Comment: Thanks. The whole thing is part of a deployment script that is distributed/shared along a number of users. They need to run this installable script and follow along the prompts  and inputs provided. If this is not possible, I guess my next step is to prompt the user for which cloud service they're currently using, then execute the corresponding cloud cli command depending on the input.